# Is there a function that returns its host cell's address?

Tags: excel-2010

how do you reference a cell's own address as an argument for use in a function that it holds.

I want to use the host cell's address within an offset function that is contained in the host cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try.

```
=CELL("address")
```

Returns:

```
$A$1
```

If you want to pass the reference to another function:

```
=INDIRECT(CELL("address"))
```

Comment: thanks this is pretty cool functions within functions "=ADDRESS(5,COLUMN(N3))=$N$3" I'll soon add this to my vlookup function